# Do I read this specific Python code properly?

Tags: python, flask, decorator

Here is a piece of the code I'm working with. I want to confirm if I am reading it properly:

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, *kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to log in first.')
            return redirect(url_for('logging')
    return wrap

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
                            title='test home title')
```

The thing that confuses me when following this along is the `f` variable.

So `Login_required()` is called as a decorator for my `index()` function. And it looks something like:

```
login_required(index()).
```

Does the `f` variable become `login_required(f())` or `login_required(index(f))`?
It confuses me in the `login_required()` function when `f` is returned with `(*args, *kwargs)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` becomes `index`.  This:

```
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
                            title='test home title')
```

Is the same as this:

```
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
                            title='test home title')
index = login_required(index)
```

That is, the decorator is called with the decorated function as its argument.